# Profiling Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, profiling

I am looking for something to do for Azure Worker Roles what New Relic and AppDynamics can do for Azure Web Roles.  I have tried both solutions for my background workers with little success.  Am I missing something in configuration for either of these services or is there another service out there that can do what I need?  I am open to hosting my own service if there is an option I run "locally".

What I'm looking for:

- See hot paths (Which methods are taking up the most CPU)
- See bottle necks (Methods that are stalling, and the callers would be nice)
- Near real-time CPU/Memory/Disk/Network usage
- Web Interface to view all of these stats

Nice to have:

- Pull windows and azure event logs from the server

Answer (score 1):

You should try Compuware's dynaTrace

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into this.  Will report back.